# How to read a string with custom terminator as a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was trying to read a text into a pandas DataFrame, but instead of 4 columns I got a lot of columns.

How to read the following text as pandas DataFrame?

```
txt="""2020-09-12, Budget, GD-0032-DD-XP, Ford,\\n 2020-04-22, Avis, D143123, Toyota,\\n 2020-04-03, Herz, 331029411, Jeep,\\n 2020-10-31, HERZ, , Hyundai,\\n 2020-09-10, Budget, Gd-1932-Ee-Rm, Chevrolet,\\n 2020-12-01, National, 9890001, Ford,\\n 2020-05-13, Alamo, W***, Hyundai,\\n 2020-01-21, Enterprise, GD-8888-TL-MP, Jeep,\\n"""
```

My attempt:

```py
txt="""2020-09-12, Budget, GD-0032-DD-XP, Ford,\n 2020-04-22, Avis, D143123, Toyota,\n 2020-04-03, Herz, 331029411, Jeep,\n 2020-10-31, HERZ, , Hyundai,\n 2020-09-10, Budget, Gd-1932-Ee-Rm, Chevrolet,\n 2020-12-01, National, 9890001, Ford,\n 2020-05-13, Alamo, W***, Hyundai,\n 2020-01-21, Enterprise, GD-8888-TL-MP, Jeep,\n"""

# input file with only ONE row
with open('input000.txt','w') as fo:
    txt = txt.replace('\n','\\n')
    fo.write(txt)

# read the data file
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input000.txt', lineterminator='\n')
df
```

My output

```
2020-09-12  Budget  GD-0032-DD-XP   Ford    \n 2020-04-22   Avis    D143123 Toyota  \n 2020-04-03   Herz    ... Ford.1  \n 2020-05-13   Alamo   W***    Hyundai.1   \n 2020-01-21   Enterprise  GD-8888-TL-MP   Jeep.1  \n
0 rows × 33 columns
```

Required output

```
    0           1       2               3
0   2020-09-12  Budget  GD-0032-DD-XP   Ford
1   2020-04-22  Avis    D143123 Toyota
2   2020-04-03  Herz    331029411   Jeep
3   2020-10-31  HERZ        Hyundai
4   2020-09-10  Budget  Gd-1932-Ee-Rm   Chevrolet
5   2020-12-01  National    9890001 Ford
6   2020-05-13  Alamo   W***    Hyundai
7   2020-01-21  Enterprise  GD-8888-TL-MP   Jeep
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass in the separator as well using `sep` parameter. Since the last element in each row also has a comma, this will result in a NaN column, so you can drop that one using `drop`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt), lineterminator='\n', sep=',').drop(columns='Unnamed: 4')
```

On a text file, `\n` seems to be converted to `\\n` and since c-engine of `read_csv` doesn't support `\\n` as a separator, perhaps it's better if we open it as a text file and build the DataFrame:

```
with open("input000.txt") as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame([line.split(',') for line in file.read().split('\\n')])
```

Output:

```
    2020-09-12       Budget   GD-0032-DD-XP        Ford
0   2020-04-22         Avis         D143123      Toyota
1   2020-04-03         Herz       331029411        Jeep
2   2020-10-31         HERZ                     Hyundai
3   2020-09-10       Budget   Gd-1932-Ee-Rm   Chevrolet
4   2020-12-01     National         9890001        Ford
5   2020-05-13        Alamo            W***     Hyundai
6   2020-01-21   Enterprise   GD-8888-TL-MP        Jeep
```

Comment: This is great, but it still fails if i read from textfile `df = pd.read_csv('input000.txt', lineterminator='\n',sep=',',header=None)
df`

Comment: The file `input000.txt` has only one line with above text as one string.

Comment: this answer is no different than `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(txt))` for the first part

Comment: @usermay14 I see. Let me try to fix it. Give me 5 mins

Comment: @usermay14 please see the edit. see if it works